# I am using BitNami Django Stack in my Mac Snow Leopard 10.6.8 . I am having trouble in finding the way to create new application in it .

Tags: django, bitnami

I am using BitNami Django Stack in my Mac Snow Leopard 10.6.8 . I am having trouble in finding the way to create new application in it as the name I selected application name *prag* which is already used in it internally . 
Please help .